# hover that moves up a div card but smoothly

Tags: html, css, hover, position, card

so I have a div which is a card and content in it. I achieved to make it moves up a bit but the transition property seems to not work.

Here is the HTML code

```
<div class="card">
  <p> Title </p>
</div>
```

and here is the CSS code

```
.card:hover {
 position: relative; 
 top: -10px;
 transition: 1s;
```

}

So basically there is multiple cards and it works well every card with the .card class moves up when the mouse is over it, but it moves instantaneously, the transition does not work. Does anyone knows how to fix it? have a great day

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have specified the `position` and `transition` only in the `:hover` block of code, meaning the transition timing is not specified until after the hover has already occurred. In other words, **only** the item that changes on hover (the `top` value) should be in the `:hover`.

Specify the `position` and `transition` outside the `:hover` block, like this for example:

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  transition: 1s
}

.card:hover {
  top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: thanks you, I had to specify the position in the .card too, and set the top to 0px in the .card, it can't run smoothly if it does not have a starting value, I guess that's what happened. However thanks you for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform: translateY`

try this

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.box:hover {
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of playing with `top` which requires a positon attribute to move it out of flow, just add a margin to displace the element:

```css
.card:hover {
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: 1s;
}


/* for visualization purpose only */
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40vh;
  width: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">Card</div
```

Comment: You should put your `transition: 1s` on the `div` element instead of in your `hover` statement. That way when a user hovers away from the `div` the element will smoothly return back to its original position